# LinearLayout not scrolling with ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout that has a lot of TextViews programatically put in. By a lot, I mean it extends beyond the bottom of my screen. I want to use a ScrollView to allow the user to scroll beyond the screen and see the rest of the TextViews. This is my activity_main.xml currently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Great! But what exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: use match_parent property for linearlayout height and width first.. and then show ur code so we can knw what have u tried...

Comment: use match_parent for your ScrollView height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Jep, make the height match_parent

Answer (score 1):

### Change your code as below !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**NOTE:** ***To see if it is scrolling or not try placing some views inside `linearLayout` like `buttons` otherwise you won't notice the screen scrolling***

Answer (score 1):

Also You Can Do Like This.It Works Well.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollData"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >



     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearWhere"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

      </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```